# How do I handle a List of Lists?

Tags: list, dart

Could someone explain what goes wrong in this piece of code?
From the code one (at least myself) would expect that after having ran this code the number list would look like `numbers = [[0], [1]]`, but instead it looks like `numbers= [[0,1], [0,1]]`.

```dart
void main() {
  int n = 2;
  List<List<int>> numbers = new List.filled(n, []);
  
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++ ){
      numbers[i].add(0);
      numbers[j].add(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems each element of your list is filled with the same instance of `[]`. 
If you then do `numbers[0].add(0);` `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]` show the added `0` because they reference the same list instance.

Changing the list initialization to

```dart
List<List<int>> numbers = new List.generate(n, (i) => []);
```

Shows your expected behavior.

Comment: yes, you're right. Indeed, every element of `number` has the same id, now I noticed this in the debugger. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and was helped by Günter Zöchbauers answer. However, to get proper control over "width" of the "array" I adjusted the code like this:

```
List <List<num>> graphArray = new List.generate(arrayMaxY, (i) => new List(arrayMaxX));
```

When arrayMaxY=3 and arrayMaxX=2, the result is:

```
[[null, null], [null, null], [null, null]]
```

What was crucial for me was that the methods `List.first` and `List.last` worked on my "array", and they do with this constructor. Also, this now works as intended:

```
graphArray[1][0] = 42;
print(graphArray); // [[null, null], [42, null], [null, null]]
```

Comment: how do you define a list of list in a class