# Initialize list of lists in Dart

Tags: for-loop, dart, closures

I have a grid in Dart implemented as follows:

```
class Cell {
    int row; 
    int col;
    Cell(this.row, this.col);
}

class Grid {
    List<List<Cell>> rows = new List(GRID_SIZE);
    Grid() {
        rows.fillRange(0, rows.length, new List(GRID_SIZE));
    }
}
```

And i can't seem to find a way to initialize each cell with the proper `row` and `col` values: I tried with two nested for loops, like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
        rows[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
    }
}
```

But due to Dart's closure error protection described [here](https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-8), my grid ends up being populated with cells having `GRID_SIZE - 1` in the `row` member.

So, what's the idiomatic way in Dart to initialize a nested list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
class Grid {
    List<List<Cell>> rows; // = new List(GRID_SIZE);
    Grid() {
        rows = new List.generate(GRID_SIZE, (i) => 
               new List.generate(GRID_SIZE, (j) => new Cell(i, j)));
    }
}
```

See also [Dart: List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118921/dart-list-of-lists/25119184#25119184)