# Dart - How to initialize a jagged array?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to initialize a jagged array of zeroes. I thought `List::filled` is the way to go, but I was wrong.

```
void main() {
  List<List<int>> matrix = new List.filled(4, new List<int>.filled(4, 0));
  print('before: $matrix');
  matrix[2][3] = 1; // change a single cell
  print('after: $matrix');
}
```

Output is not correct. Despite of the `new` keyword, Dart reused sublists:

> before: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>   after: [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0,1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

What's the correct way to initialize a jagged array, so that each sub array are not merely pointers to the same list?

Comment: Why not use Matrix class directly?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look at that. But the question still stands, on `how to initialize a jagged array`.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118921/dart-list-of-lists. But since this question already has an answer and is worded very differently, I won't delete it, so that others can reach here with alternative search queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List.generate` instead of `List.filled` if each index should have unique value:

```
var matrix = List.generate(4, (_) => List.filled(4, 0));
```